# Is there a way to lazyload the image in CardMedia component in material ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, material-ui, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazy load the image in the CardMedia component. Is there an attribute i can use or any other way to incorporate the lazy loading of the image in the component.

```css
<CardMedia
    key={cardIndex}
    component="img"
    style={{objectFit: 'contain', height: props.height}}
    image={(cardItem)}
 />
```

Answer (score 3):

Fortnately, yes.
Once you have added `component="img"` prop, you have access to `loading` prop in the component. Set it to `loading='lazy'` and you are good to go.

```
    <CardMedia key={cardIndex} component="img" loading="lazy" image="{(cardItem)} />
```